# Rust: double linked list

Tags: rust

I'm a beginner in Rust. So the answer will be simple.

I try to write something which can be simplified to a double linked list. In other languages I would use a struct with pointers to the both neighbours. I can iterate through it and ste some data.
But how to solve it in rust? I would have two writable references to each node and as far as I know this is not possible.

Comment: *"the answer will be simple"* - there's essentially a whole book about how to write a (doubly) linked list! [Learn Rust With Entirely Too Many Linked Lists](https://rust-unofficial.github.io/too-many-lists/index.html). It is not simple and not particularly recommended unless its a learning exercise you're invested in.

Comment: Note that if you really wanna simplify the task, you can use `gc` crate. It, however, is really far from the best option

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

Rust ownership rules state that each value can only have one owner at a time. But in doubly linked list each node will have two owners. We use [Rc smart pointer](https://web.mit.edu/rust-lang_v1.25/arch/amd64_ubuntu1404/share/doc/rust/html/book/second-edition/ch15-04-rc.html)

```
  use std::rc::Rc;
```

> To enable multiple ownership, Rust has a type called Rc. Its name
> is an abbreviation for reference counting, which keeps track of the
> number of references to a value to know whether or not a value is
> still in use. If there are zero references to a value, the value can
> be cleaned up without any references becoming invalid.

But the thing is a value owned by an Rc pointer is immutable. it is read-only. You might need to modify each node. that is why you need to use `RefCell`

```
use std::cell::RefCell;
```

That being said, you can create a doubly linked list with struct in Rust.

```
struct List<T>{
    head:Pointer<T>,
    tail:Pointer<T>
}

struct Node<T>{
    element:T,
    next:Pointer<T>,
    prev:Pointer<T>,
}
// you need multiple owners who can mutate the data
// type is option because last_node.next will be Null
type Pointer<T>=Option<Rc<RefCell<Node<T>>>>;
```

Comment: Thanks for the good and detailed answer.

Comment: @MatthiasF. Actually, version with `RefCell` can't be as performant as `unsafe` version, because it adds runtime checks. Correct production-ready linked list has to use `unsafe` https://rust-unofficial.github.io/too-many-lists/sixth-final.html , and to API consumer it is safe to use. Notice that same author has safe version, and he critiques it a lot https://rust-unofficial.github.io/too-many-lists/fourth-final.html

Answer (score 3):

Rust is not really the ideal language for implementing a linked list.
There is no unique ownership by design, so Rust's type system will have a bit of a hard time.

I guess this is more of a learning thing, than something productive in which case you should consider alternatives to linked lists.

Anyway, you can do it by using `Rc<Cell<Node>>`.

The `Rc` allows you to have multiple owners by reference counting. And the `Cell` allows you to change the Node, even if there are active references.

Comment: Actually, this solution is not good, we can see reasons at https://rust-unofficial.github.io/too-many-lists/fourth-final.html , like `Oh, I guess it's also riddled with tons of "unnecessary" runtime checks for correctness between Rc and RefCell. I put unnecessary in quotes because they're actually necessary to guarantee the whole actually being safe thing.`

Comment: Thank you, this seems to be that what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

There is a link on how to do it https://rust-unofficial.github.io/too-many-lists/sixth-final.html

It uses `unsafe`, but `unsafe` is necessary, because safe version https://rust-unofficial.github.io/too-many-lists/fourth-final.html uses `RefCell`, which adds runtime checks and can't be as performant as `unsafe` version. Notice that we can avoid runtime checks, because we can prove safety of `unsafe` code, and to API consumer all public methods are safe.

In general, when Rust's safety features prevent you from doing something, use `unsafe` features and write Rust code ~same(same as in shoot your leg same, like in C++, but as performant as in C++) as C++. This way you will have safest possible code(safer than in any other programming language, including garbage-collected ones) when static analyzer can help you automate safety checks, and ~same(same as in shoot your leg same, like in C++, but as performant as in C++) code as in C++ when static analyzer is not good enough to handle some cases

Comment: "when Rust's safety features prevent you from doing something, just use unsafe features and write Rust code ~same as C++". This is a **very bad** advice. When you cannot write something in safe rust you should think really hard **why** what you are trying to do is not allowed and do you really **need** that. "This way you will have safest possible code". This is also not true. When you introduce UB your whole program is invalid and you **cannot** rely on any safety features from safe rust.

Comment: You also cannot just "write Rust code ~same as C++", since they are very different languages and have different memory safety rules. If you do not understand **very well** rust's safety rules you should not write unsafe code. You probably don't really need it, and if you do then someone who knows what they are doing has probably already done it and published well tested crate.

Comment: @AleksanderKrauze I updated answer to more clearly specify what I meant by same - `same as in shoot your leg same, like in C++`. Unfortunately, static analyzer can't handle all cases, or we can't do same stuff without unsafe as efficiently as in C++. Hence we do need to use unsafe in some cases, for example, this case https://rust-unofficial.github.io/too-many-lists/sixth-final.html was chosen to be production by author, although there is a safe version https://rust-unofficial.github.io/too-many-lists/fourth-final.html